# SUM first consecutive rows only SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query, syntax, data

I have the following data:

```
ROW SEGMENT ORDEN   LONG
1   39       11     49.00
2   39       10     102.00
5   39       7      104.00
6   39       6      139.00
7   39       5      97.00
11  39       1      59.00
```

First, I want to group by **SEGMENT** and sum the column **LONG** for first consecutive rows only (column **ORDEN**). 
The colum **ORDEN** is is always ordered in descending order

[image]

I want the following result:

```
SEGMENT  SUMLONG
39        151.00
```

Where 151.00 is the result of adding 49.00  plus 102.00.

Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

Test:

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, 
                 orden + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY segment ORDER BY orden) grp 
          FROM sourcetable ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT segment, 
                 grp, 
                 SUM(long) sum_long
          FROM cte1
          GROUP BY segment, 
                   grp )
SELECT DISTINCT
       segment, 
       FIRST_VALUE(sum_long) OVER (PARTITION BY segment ORDER BY grp DESC) sum_long
FROM cte2
```